# Writing an app which can be updated across devices

Tags: android, ios, google-app-engine, amazon-ec2, cloud

I am interested in creating an app which can run across devices (think Kindle app). The main requirement I have is this: if the user chooses to use my app using multiple devices then whenever he opens the app, irrespective of the device, he should find the app in it's latest state.

I looked around to see if Google App Engine or EC2 or Azure provide this kind of a service, where they push update the files, but could not find one. It would be great if you can point me to the right resources or suggest alternatives to how I could go about implementing this app.

Thanks,
M

Comment: It seems like iCloud is gonna have to be your main man in this situation.  Maybe pushing a plist put to your devices over the cloud would get the synchronization feature working, but it begs the question: what happens when there is no Internet connection?

Comment: What sort of app? What sort of devices? There's no ready-made recipe for this, because the number of ways you might want to sync data is near infinite.

Comment: I was thinking of an app like Kindle. I like how Kindle synchronizes the book status across devices (in my case my android Tablet, phone and the cloud reader). @NickJohnson you say there are many ways one might want to synchronize the data, could you please list a few?

Thanks,
M

Answer (score 2):

Go with an HTML5 App that can respond to different platforms such as iPhone, iPad, Android, Windows Phone and resize the screens based on the device. There are frameworks such as phone gap that will let you build easily and host it on EC2 or Azure.

Comment: This is a great solution, too, if you're not married to the idea of writing native apps.  It's easier to create and maintain one mobile site with several build configurations than to deal with multiple full code bases in different languages for different platforms, and there are frameworks such as [jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) and [Sencha touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch) that make things look almost native on various devices.  [Phone Gap](http://phonegap.com/) makes it easy to package one web app into native apps for several different devices.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if iCloud plays nicely with Android, or what its API looks like.  Maybe that works.

Either way, CodaFi is on the right track.  You'll need server-side storage in some form.  Persist what you need of the application state during shutdown by POSTing the relevant settings, storing them in a database by user uuid, then retrieving them on startup.

You'll need a way to associate each user's various devices with each other.  This probably means implementing a login system with basic auth or oauth.

[edit] In the case of no network connection, you'll have to just load the last state the app was in on the current device -- you can save that locally as well.

[edit 2] App Engine, EC2, or Azure would be reasonable hosting solutions for this, but they don't build the server code for you.  I'm most familiar with python/Django, and using that stack (or whichever you're comfortable with) it would be pretty straightforward to set up a web api and a database backend to handle what you need.

Amazon's tools offer great power - you spin up virtual machines on which you have root access.  You configure the server from the os up.  I'm not sure if you can get started for free, though, like I know you can with App Engine.  I also don't know if they offer simpler hosting solutions with specific software stacks preinstalled.

App engine looks like an especially good choice if you're planning on a low amount of traffic, as you can probably keep it free.  Also a good choice for someone less familiar with server administration and who doesn't need anything too fancy.

Comment: My apologies, I didn't see the android tag... Well anyways, +1, he definitely needs a server.

Comment: From your response it sounds like I will have to implement the entire synchronization in the app and I am not going to get any particular support from the App Engine.

Thanks for your response.

Comment: Don't stop here.  It's entirely likely that I'm overlooking a solution that will really help you.  For example, you could probably even use Dropbox's api to store and retrieve a json file for each user, just saved by user uuid. There are probably solutions better designed to do what you need - it depends on what exactly you need to store, how often it will be read and written, how many users you'll have, etc.  My point is just that App Engine and EC2 don't give you much automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some kind of backend service for mobile apps and store your app states online. If I may point to our own product, we are working on such a cross-platform backend solution called CloudyRec and supports iOS, Android and WP7 among others.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the OpenMobster Sync Platform for Android and iOS. You can sync your app's state with the backend and in doing so replicate the data to other devices owned by you, just like iCloud. The Sync + Replicate functionality comes out of the box in the platform. On the device side there is a very simple API for the data to be managed by the Sync Engine. The platform is free and open source

For more details please see here: http://www.openmobster.com/sync_platform.html

Full Disclosure: I am the CEO of OpenMobster, Open Source Mobile Backend As a Service platform